# Firebase where() is not working to make a query

Tags: javascript, firebase

I got a problem when I tried to use where() to query my Database, First I add data to DB which is like
this:

```
addComment() { // works
    db.collection("cities").doc("LA").add({
    content: "Test 123456"
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log("Document successfully written!");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
    });
}
```

The addComment works, but when I try to use .update() method to modify the data, it failed

---

This function failed, it shows : where(...).update is not a function.
// I also tried .set(), .delete(), method it just don't work

```
editComment() { // don't work
    db.collection("cities").where("content", "==", "Test 123456").update({
            content: "Test 654321"
            })
            .then(function() {
                console.log("Document successfully written!");
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use the "where" method you are getting back a [querysnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) and this doesn't have the methods (update, add, set, delete). if you want to use this methods you should get a [documentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) using the **doc** method.

Now, if you want to keep using the where method then you should loop over the result of the `querysnapshot.docs` then reference every document and CRUD them. something like this:

```
    editComment() {
        db.collection("cities").where("content", "==", "Test123456").then(querysnapshot => {
        querysnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        doc.ref.update({
                   content: "Test 654321"
                  })
         })
    
      })
    
    }
```